# Remove external include depedency from codebase

Tags: c++

My task is to remove inclusion of C library headers from our C++ codebase. As first to remove the lib header files first I declare its included functions as exter type

```
extern "C"
{
        typedef unsigned int uint;
        uint function1(...);
        All library methods goes in here
}
```

The code compiles and links fine - but how can I remove the typedef - the uint type is defined in the C library header file?

Comment: So your codebase is still gonna use the library, but not the header?

Comment: Yes - the issue is that if we include the C library header then we also need to include all its dependent headers, which is what we want to avoid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `typedef` is just another name for a type. If you don't wish to use `uint`, then declare that function with the type `uint` is aliasing, like this:

```
unsigned int function1(...);
```

Comment: Thanks it solved my issue - but just one consideration - if the C library function return type changes - chances are really remote then we need to modify it here again

Comment: @Prakash - A library that does such a breaking change without warning is... not that great. Alias or no alias.

Comment: I understand and we can fix then the compilation issue - but is there a way by which typedef can also be made to be included as extern

Comment: @Prakash - A `typedef` doesn't have language linkage. And you can't "forward declare" it. The type it stands for must be known.